# extracting terms prints distorted tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using `urllib2`, `BeautifulSoup` and [`topia.termextract`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/topia.termextract/1.1.0) modules in python 2.7 to extract terms reading paragraphs of website

```
>>> extractor("he is Programmer, Visionary Entrepreneur and Investor ")
[('Entrepreneur', 1, 1), ('Programmer', 1, 1), ('Visionary', 1, 1), ('Investor', 1, 1), ('Visionary Entrepreneur', 1, 2)]
```

This works fine with a paragraph

**but in loop below**

```
>>> def getTerms(website):
        page = urllib2.urlopen(website)
        text = page.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

        for para in soup.findAll('p'):
            print extractor(para.text)
```

Passing a webpage url to the function above **Prints**

```
[(u'Entrepreneur', 1, 1), (u'Programmer', 1, 1), (u'Visionary', 1, 1), (u'Investor', 1, 1), (u'Visionary Entrepreneur', 1, 2)] .....
```

There is `u` printed in starting of tuples ? how can i retrieve the pure tuples form ?

Note: Only printing `para.text` is printing pure text paragraphs in loop above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are Unicode strings(hence the u'') format. The 'u' is not part of the string but indicates its format.

```
>>> s='abc'
>>> type(s)
<type 'str'>
>>> s=u'abc'
>>> type(s)
<type 'unicode'>
```

If you are dealing with third party web sites, you will need to deal with Unicode (because you are eventually going to meet a site which is not in American English).

Please read this section of the python docs thoroughly: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Or better yet, switch to Python 3 where Unicode is the default format for strings.